# How do I generate an image from a matrix (with floating point entries)

Tags: matlab

I have a 10 by 10 matrix (data by name). I are trying to generate an image:

```
figure; 
(data);
colormap(gray);
```

The saved image is 560*420. How can I generate a 10 by 10 image?

Also I want to know how it works. Does it first set the -ve entries of the matrix to `0`, entries >1 to `1` and then multiply all the entries by 255 (like `imwrite()`)?

Is there any other function in MATLAB to directly convert from floating values (without converting it to RGB, 0<=value<=1) to generate an image?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find the duplicate. You use the [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) function to display a matrix as an image. So your above code should read:

```
figure; 
imagesc(data);
colormap(gray);
```

The color scaling is controlled by [`caxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html), which takes arguments as `caxis([cmin, cmax])`. From the docs:

> `caxis([cmin cmax])` sets the color limits to specified minimum and maximum values. Data values less than `cmin` or greater than `cmax` map to `cmin` and `cmax`, respectively. Values between `cmin` and `cmax` linearly map to the current colormap.

So in this case, the lowest value (if you haven't set a `caxis`) will be mapped to the lowest color in the gray colormap (white) and the highest value will be set to black. To see what values of RGB are used in setting the grayscale colormap, assign it to a variable and take a look at the values (or plot it).

```
gray=colormap('gray');
```

Also, read through the documentation on [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html)

Answer (score 2):

May be you could find ["image"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) function from "Image Processing Matlab toolbox" relevant to what you want to do

As you can see you can illustrate matrix C, by running simply something like

```
image(C)
```

About you second question resizing the picture, there is

```
imresize(C)
B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols])
```

which [its](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html) arguments shows how [it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html) works,

Regarding the way that it depict any matrix, Image can be indexed or true color. An indexed image stores colors as an array of indices into the figure colormap. Instead, the color values for each pixel are stored directly as RGB triplets ( R, G, B) .So any image can be called as an (m-by-n-by-3) array. This array consists of three m-by-n matrices (representing the red, green, and blue color planes).

I believe the best way to learn matlab is going through its help and following its "Getting Started"

Comment: My be for next time, you could organize your question and ask 1 in time, then answering would be easier for other users